# Is there a to tell if someone wrote a WebView wrapper for my webapp?

Tags: javascript, android, ios

I wrote a webapp and recently had someone creating an app for Android that is only a WebView wrapper. This is a security issue as whoever created this could potentially be collecting my webapp user login details.
So is there a way with JavaScript or server side to tell if the application is running inside a webview?

Comment: "This is a security issue as whoever created this could potentially be collecting my webapp user login details" -- as can any Web browser developer and many browser plugin developers. What are you doing to stop those developers? And, if the answer is "nothing", why aren't you worrying about those too?

Answer (score 0):

try setting X-Frame-Options to deny on your server, WebView should then not work anymore
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options